# No module named error but pip freeze shows module is instealled in virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I'm currently writing a Flask app using virtual env. When I try and run some of my python files I am getting:
`ImportError: No module named <module>`

In this case, the module I am trying to use is 'Click'. If I do a `pip freeze` or a `pip list` inside the virtual env, I can see the module listed there. I'm inside my virtual env when I'm trying to run the .py file too. How come pip freeze/list can find the module but my .py program cannot? Could it also be an issue with my .wsgi file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've just figured this out, the path in my .wsgi file for "activate_this.py" was incorrect because I was trying to run it in an EC2 instance instead of my normal directory. After changing the path things seem to be working again :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the line pointing to "activate_this.py" needs to be above the import statements in order for this to work. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be?